# Spring JPA, additional database manipulation when updating properties of an entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa, domain-driven-design

I am designing an e-commerce web application using Spring JPA. I have 2 classes `Product` and `Category`, where a `Product` can be assigned to many categories, but a `Category` does not concern about `Product`.

```
@Entity(name = "products")
class Product {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Long productId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "product_category_links",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "category_id"))
    private List<Category> categories;

    // getters, setters,
}

@Entity(name = "categories")
class Category {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Long category_id;

    // getters, setters
}
```

When a `Product` has its categories changed, I have a requirement to also update something in database. I am thinking of maintain this integrity by creating a dedicated service method to update product's category.

```
class ProductService
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    private ComplexDBService complexDBService;

    @Transactional
    public void addCategory(Long productId, Long categoryId) {
        Product p = productRepository.findByProductId(productId);
        Category c = categoryRepository.findByCategoryId(categoryId);
        p.getCategories.add(c);
        complexDBService.doSomething();
    }
}
```

But I think this is not practical because a `Product` can still have categories changed in other places. For example, in a controller, someone can get a `Product` directly from the repository can change its categories. I don't want to forbid this use case.

So I am thinking of putting the logic `addCategory(Long productId, Long categoryId)` in `Product` class itself, which actually suggested by Domain Driven Design. But I cannot figure out how to do that because I cannot inject the `ComplextDBService` into `Product`. One way is to pass it as an argument to `addCategory` method as `addCategory(Long productId, Long categoryId, ComplextDBService complexDBService)`, is this a good practice? **Is there some other ways to put custom database manipulation logic in a domain class?**

Comment: Unfortunately DB persistence is obstructing your DDD models.

Comment: What exactly do you need to do when you add a product to different categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> addCategory(Long productId, Long categoryId, ComplextDBService complexDBService), is this a good practice?

No, it isn't. In complicated business cases, you sometime have to pass some kind of "service" as a parameter into method invoked on aggregate, but as a rule of thumb you should only invoke read-only-query method on this "service".

> Is there some other ways to put custom database manipulation logic in a domain class?

There should only occur Product related things inside Product aggregate, e.g. manipulation of Product state.
Your requirement is to respond to occurrence inside Product aggregate.

**Domain Event to the rescue**

You need to invert the control. Product aggregate should inform the outside about Events inside itself and the outside should react to this. Product should not depend on other not related aggregates/concepts.

```
class Product {
    void addCategory(CategorySnapshot category) {
        categories.add(category);
        eventPublisher.publish(new ProductCategoryAdded(getSnapshot(), category));
    }
}
```

Now you should register other components to listen to ProductCategoryAdded event, it doesn’t matter what those other components are (if you need to make db operations, maybe you are implementing CQRS?).

You can implement publisher by yourself or use frameworks like Guava Event Bus, Axon etc.

By the way, you are missing lots of important concepts of DDD.

1. Aggregate-Product should not have list of other Aggregate-Category (**maybe this bounded-context of your project should not be implemented using DDD at all?**)
2. You should not add objects directly into list owned by aggregate `p.getCategories.add(c)`
3. `//getters, setters` - those are not object-oriented…